# Virtuoso crash "search.c:326 box_serial_length not supported for data type"

Tags: rdf, virtuoso, turtle-rdf, rdf4j

I am connecting to a Virtuoso 7.20.3216 compiled and installed inside a VirtualBox CentOS 7.3 64bit, using the RDF4J Virtuoso adapter.

I try to load a Turtle file in Virtuoso using this code :

```
Repository r = new virtuoso.rdf4j.driver.VirtuosoRepository(url, login, password);
RepositoryConnection connection = r.openConnection();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// Turtle data written inside baos

String graphUri = ... ;
connection.add(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()), RDF.NAMESPACE, RDFFormat.TURTLE, SimpleValueFactory.getInstance().createIRI(graphUri));
```

Virtuoso crashes (stops) with the following logs :

```
12:10:01 box_serial_len called with dtp 225
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x8c6d3a]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x8c6d98]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x4fba85]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x629664]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x629997]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x622485]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x65233d]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x6524dd]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x592328]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x59a807]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x59760a]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x5c0e30]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x5ca63b]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x59370c]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x597d13]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x5c0e30]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x5cbeee]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x5d3d36]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t(sf_sql_execute_w+0x7b) [0x5d3edb]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x8cb297]
12:10:01 /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t() [0x8d1683]
12:10:01 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e25) [0x7fe04db7ee25]
12:10:01 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fe04d3a634d]
12:10:01 GPF: search.c:326 box_serial_length not supported for data type
```

The same Turtle string, when uploaded to the conductor back-office, works properly. The file is pretty large so I can't paste it here.

We have narrowed down the problem to a character encoding issue. The turtle file contains literals with accented characters such as `"Disque à gravure directe"@fr`.

We haven't set any character encoding parameters, neither on the Virtuoso config side, nor in the JDBC connection side. We tried by adding `charset=UTF-8` in the JDBC connection string, with no luck.

It seems also that the problem only arises when the database is empty. When the database already contains some data, Virtuoso does not crash.

Any idea on

1. what the error message means?
2. what could be the cause of the problem?
3. how to fix or work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, this question is only for Virtuoso developers, thus, it should be asked on the Virtuoso mailing list. I mean it's more or less a bug report with some core dump produced once you enable the appropriate log level in the virtuoso.ini file.

Comment: Please ensure that all [client-side components](https://www.openlinksw.com/oat/wiki/main/Main/VirtSesame2Provider) are current builds. Then I would suggest you recompile based on the [latest `develop/7` branch code](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource), which will bring you to `7.20.3219` or later, and retest. If the issue persists, please log an issue on the [github project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues).

Comment: I was hoping Openlink folks were lurking on Stakoverflow, and to be honest I wasn't sure where was the best place to ask. I have sent a message on the mailing list at https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/message/36089665/ and so will close this question.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been verified and [logged as issue #697 on the github project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/697). Resolution work is in progress.

Further updates will be posted [to the issue on github](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/697).